# Jquery hide/show not working in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of HTML/JQuery code that only seems to be working for IE 8.  I am attempting to embed a meebo chat widget into a wiki by adding some direct html code.  I don't want the widget to load by default, as it takes a bit of time, so I am putting it in a div and hiding it using Jquery.

Unfortunately, this only seems to work in Internet Explorer.  In Firefox 3, when I click on the toggle button, nothing happens.  When I tried in Google Chrome, the show/hide text would toggle, but the embedding widget doesn't show up.

Does anyone know if this is an issue using JQuery, or perhaps a browser compatibility issue?  There is a lot of backend wiki code that could be affecting the issue as well.  For instance, the place where I embed the widget is nested in both tables and other divs.  Could this be causing problems with the JQuery selectors?

Any help would be appreciated.

### Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn-slide").click(function(e){ 
       e.preventDefault();

       $("#meebo-panel").toggleClass("meebo-open").toggleClass("meebo-closed").toggleClass("meebo-hide").toggleClass("meebo-show");
       $(".btn-slide").toggleClass("show-text").toggleClass("hide-text");
       $(".show-hide-panel").toggleClass("green-panel").toggleClass("grey-panel");

       $(".meebo-show").show();
       $(".meebo-hide").hide();

       $(".show-text").text("Chat with me");
       $(".hide-text").text("Hide");
       return false;      
    });
});
```

### My HTML:

```
<div class="show-hide-panel green-panel"><a href="#" class="btn-slide show-text">Chat now</a></div>
<div id="meebo-panel" class="meebo-closed meebo-hide">
    Test
</div>
```

EDIT: It appears that this issue occurs regardless of what is in the div.  I simplified the example to include text instead, since I believe it streamlines the code a bit.

Comment: I wonder if its because of the flash widget. I've had troubles with flash an animations. Try replacing the <object> tag with just plain text and see if that is the issue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Benny.  It looks like it is an issue even with plain text.  I've updated the example to use text, as you've now eliminated this being a problem with the embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  The issue was that the wiki backend was already including a different (and older) version of JQuery.

To fix this, I needed to use the core JQuery function [noConflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)().

My code ended up looking like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Do jQuery stuff using $
        ...
        ...
});
</script>
```

This fixed all the issues of conflicting JQuery libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you js is fine mate i think. there is something wrong with your markup.

you have got an object tag and then inside it a param which is fine but its being closed with an embed.

Object tag for ie
Embed for ff

hope this helps

Comment: Nice catch, Ali - this was actually just a typo when I was trying to obfuscate my code a bit.  The real version doesn't have this problem.  in fact - I can replace all the embedding code with simple text and it will exhibit the same issue.