# Jquery .show() not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, show

I have a problem with the jquery show function in firefox.

Situation:
I have loaded a iframe with an aspx page in a popup (fancybox). In that aspx page I have a button with an onclick event which calls a custom function and in that function it fires the .show() function on a div. This div has a style element which contains: display:none;.

This works in IE, safari, chrome. This even works in firefox when I load the aspx page standalone. It doesnt work in firefox in the fancybox-iframe popup. I get no javascript errors. Even the display:none is removed from the style attribute, but the div doesnt show up.

The html from the page

```
<div class="popupWrapper">
  ..some elements
  <div id="psharebutton" style="display:none;"> 
   ..content of the div
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code:

```
function dolinkedin(url, title, summary, source) {
        $(".smbutton").addClass("buttonDisabled");
        $("#linklinkedin").removeClass("buttonDisabled");
        $("#psharebutton").show();

        parent.sizeFancybox();
    }
```

The button where the popup is triggered, is a anchor, which has the fancyboxiframe class. Fancybox will automaticly generate the js code for showing the popup.

I have checked these topics:

- [Jquery Hide/Show not working in Firefox Only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945043/jquery-hide-show-not-working-in-firefox-only)
- [Jquery hide/show not working in Firefox/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972056/jquery-hide-show-not-working-in-firefox-chrome)
- [Jquery .show() and .hide() or even .css({"display":"none"}); not working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644109/jquery-show-and-hide-or-even-cssdisplaynone-not-working-in-fire)

I have checked if my html is valid and it is.

Any idea?

BHD

Comment: have you tried $("#psharebutton").toggle(); ?

Comment: I don't have the code te reproduce anymore :( Sorry about that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to do

```
$("#psharebutton").css("display", "inline-block");
```

instead of

```
$("#psharebutton").show();
```

A jquery "show" is identical to setting the display style attribute to "block".  I found that I needed "inline-block" for firefox and chrome (I didn't need this for IE).  I believe (but have not confirmed) that jquery is smart enough to know what the previous display value is and use that, but in my case I started out with display set to "none" so there was no previous value.

Comment: Your answer and the answer of DJ were probably the solution, unfortunately I can't reproduce it anymore, but after seeing similar behavior I'm quit sure that was indeed the case. I up voted both your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I did set this in my css:

```
body { display: none }
```

and tried to change this in jQuery:

```
$("body").show();
```

which did not work in Firefox.

After I changed the HTML to

```
<body style="display: none">
```

and removing the part from CSS I was able to use jQuery show(); flawless

It seems that the inheritance of css rules does not follow the same routine in Firefox as in IE / Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's probably helpful for others :)

Answer (score 1):

Just write down like $("#psharebutton").attr('display','') or $("#psharebutton").attr('display','block').

```
function dolinkedin(url, title, summary, source) {
        $(".smbutton").addClass("buttonDisabled");
        $("#linklinkedin").removeClass("buttonDisabled");
        $("#psharebutton").attr('display','');

        parent.sizeFancybox();
    }
```

Comment: See my comment at kirk :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be just a side-effect of a js error. It's always worth hitting F12 and seeing if there are any js errors in the console. I had a similar issue where I couldn't figure out why .show() wasn't working on an input that had a style of 'display:none' in Firefox and it turned out I had a badly formed selector which was missing a closing ] and threw an error you don't see, until you open Firebug. Chrome was more tolerant showed the button while Firefox caught the bad selector.